# Make array iteration faster using views

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

If I have a large numpy array `x` I can speed up many iterative operations, like instead of writing

```
x[1:-1] = 5*x[1:-1]
```

I can use

```
x[1:-1] *= 5
```

which is faster, because in contrast to the first example it avoids the unnecessary creation of an additional array with the values `5*x[1:-1]`.

Here comes my question: Is it possible to speed up a more general iteration like

```
x[1:-1] = 5*x[1:-1] + x[:-2]
```

in a similar way? So far I only came up with

```
x[1:-1] = x[:-2]
x[1:-1] += 5*x[2:]
```

but this still creates copies and I wonder if there is a way to become faster.

Comment: You could do it in a single sweep, in-place

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you just need temporary arryas, and you can't rewrite

```
x[1:-1] += 5*x[2:]
```

as operations on a view.

The analog to in-place calculations when you need temporary arrays is to create a few temporary arrays and use those for the output at each stage of the calculation.  You still have a bit more pointer math, but you won't have to create the space in memory more than once.  Then you can rewrite the line above to:

```
np.multiply(x[2:], 5, out=temp)
x[1:-1] += temp
```

Here, I assume `temp` has the size `x[-1:1]` which is what I usually do for this common issue of dealing with boundaries.

With the in-place calculations you can't run the exact equation with timeit many times because the numbers grow exponentially, but here's a test with the 5x replaced by 1x:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

N = 100000000
x = np.arange(N, dtype=np.int)
temp = np.zeros((N-2,), dtype=np.int)

def f0(x, temp):
    x[1:-1] += 1*x[2:]

def f1(x, temp):
    np.multiply(x[1:-1], 1, out=temp)
    x[1:-1] += temp

print timeit("f0(x, temp)", "from __main__ import f0, f1, x, temp", number=100)
print timeit("f1(x, temp)", "from __main__ import f0, f1, x, temp", number=100)
```

which gives:

```
71.543628931
44.719383955

# or, for N /= 100, and number *= 10
5.37844896317
4.50015997887
```

and for much smaller arrays, the `out` array approach can become slower.